# How can I get the index in a series?

Tags: python, list

I have the data series including these labels for my dataset:

`s=['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D']`

I would like to know how can I get the index of first element `B` and the last element of `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index of the first element B

```
s.index('B')
```

Index of the last element C

```
len(s) - s[::-1].index('C') - 1
```